# Каким образом можно создать кастомное диалоговое окно

Tags: c++, winapi

Добрый день.
Хочу написать программу которая будет иметь нестандартный вид окна.
Все мы знаем как выглядят дефолтные окна в самой Windows. Но встречаются программы которые выглядят иначе. К примеру проигрыватели, nero(если кто еще помнит). 
Я хочу сделать окно в виде тетрадного листа. Я сделал скан листа тетради, но каким образом прикрутить этот лист в качестве окна программы с кнопками(опять же хотелось бы их тоже сделать не стандартными) в инете я не нашел. Кое какая информация есть по C#. Но нужен именно С++.
Если важно, то среда разработки MVS 2015.

Comment: Qt то не подойдет ?

Comment: Я его совсем не знаю. Пару видеоуроков смотрел и на этом мое знакомство окончилось. 
Пока что использую то, что сразу установил.

Comment: Окно можно сделать без рамки, без верхних кнопок управления, вообще без всего. Это есть в документации. Посмотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Если нет нужды именно в WinAPI, то лучше потратьте время на изучение Qt(его нужно гораздо меньше, чем на WinAPI). Иначе скоро Вы будете проклинать свой выбор.

Comment: Видимо да. Потому что многое что я хотел бы сделать. В qt гораздо проще и больше документации. Этот же пример, который мне нужен в qt решился быстро. Наверное надо переезжать на QT:)